# Is this an error in Rudin's Complex Analysis in defining chains?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

In Rudin's Complex Analysis, chains are defined, as I understand it, as members of the quotient of the free abelian monoid with all $C^1$ curves as basis by the equivalence relation $\gamma_1\gamma_2\cdots\gamma_n \sim \delta_1\delta_2\cdots\delta_m \iff \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\gamma_k} f\ dz = \sum_{k=1}^m \int_{\delta_k} f\ dz,\ \forall f \in C\left(\gamma_1^* \cup \gamma_2^* \cup \cdots \cup \gamma_n^* \cup \delta_1^* \cup \delta_2^* \cup \cdots \cup \delta_m^*\right)$

See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358331/definition-of-chain-rudin) that asks about ways of defining chains in complex analysis. I believe Rudin's definition is the third one in the answer there.

Then, in the book, he proceeds to define $\Gamma^*$ for a chain $\Gamma = \gamma_1\ \dot+\ \gamma_2\ \dot+\ \cdots\ \dot+\ \gamma_n$ (which is to be understood as the equivalence class of the string $\gamma_1\gamma_2\cdots\gamma_n$) as $$\Gamma^* = \gamma_1^* \cup \gamma_2^* \cup \cdots \cup \gamma_n^*$$

However, I don't think this is well defined. The problem comes in when considering the two constant paths $\gamma_1 \equiv k_1$ and $\gamma_2 \equiv k_2$ and the chains $\Gamma_1 = \gamma_1, \Gamma_2 = \gamma_2$ (again, to be understood as their equivalence classes). Then $\int_{\Gamma_1} = \int_{\Gamma_2} = 0 \implies \Gamma_1 = \Gamma_2$ but $\Gamma_1^* = \{k_1\} \ne \{k_2\} = \Gamma_2^*$. Also, I'm not exactly sure whether the empty string should be a part of this definition, but if it is and we denote the empty chain thereof by $\Phi$, then $\Phi^* = \varnothing$ and again $\int_\Phi = 0$ (by empty sum).

What I think Rudin actually wanted to do (also provided that he defines $\Gamma^*$ before explaining chain equality in his rather informal definition of chains that doesn't actually use any of the terms *free abelian monoid*, *equivalence relation/class*, *quotient*) was define chains as just the free abelian monoid of all $C^1$ paths and then introduce an equivalence relation on them $\simeq$ but instead he used the equality symbol $=$ and called related terms *equal* instead of *equivalent*.

This might be just an abuse of language and notation, but I want to know: 
Is my thinking right? 
Also, could we, in any way, define the set of chains as a group (the identification above being used in order to take into account orientation and allowing cancelation) but also well-define $\Gamma^*$?